# How to Integrate Chart.Funnel.js in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, polymer, chart.js, vaadin

I am new to JS and polymer and i am using Chart.js in my polymer component. Now there is a Chart.funnel.js which is a plugin for Chart.js and provide the "funnel" chart. However i am not really sure how to include this file into Chart.js using plugin service. or there might be whole different way of doing it. any help would be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/chart.funnel.js" ></script>
```

If I understamd it correctly, I need to register the plugin using plugin service ;

```
Chart.pluginService.register(???);
```

now i am not sure what to put inside the (???).  Basically i am not able to find the global property for the chart.funnel.js.

the Chart.Funnel.js is available here https://github.com/xch89820/Chart.Funnel.js/blob/master/dist/chart.funnel.js

I expect some a library instance like here https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/guide/getting-started.html#integration

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem, It was a misunderstanding from my side. Basically, A new Charttype  needs to register its self in the controller of Chart.js by itself.

see  [new charts in Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/charts.html).

In my case it was enought to load the js plugin after the chart was loaded, so the funnel chart plugin Register itself.